# Node Webkit - Interactive pop ups

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

Looking to see if anyone has an answer for me. Looking to have a node webkit application with an interactive popup, perhaps HTML5 growl with a input field. Is this possible with node webkit?

Comment: You mean a modal?  Yes, you can have modals in node-webkit.

Comment: Not a modal, this popup will be the bottom right corner. much like what i see here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nw-notify

But i wish to have an input field to reply to.

Comment: Yes, anything you see in web applications can be built into a node webkit application.

Comment: Yes, nwjs allow to create any number of windows with any content.